# Why does this React async useEffect behave differently in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, firefox

In React, I have an async function that takes a set function, calls an API endpoint, and then calls the set function on the returned data from the API, returning the Promise created by this set function.  This call has a callback which sets a loaded variable to true, then rendering the page.

When viewed in Chrome/Vivaldi, the page makes one network call, as seen in my network tab.
[image: One upload]

However, when viewed in Firefox, it makes a large number of network calls to the same endpoint, possibly until the first one succeeds,but eventually stops, as shown below. (with sensitive addresses replaced by peppers)

[image]

Below, here is the source code:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";

async function getScheduled(setScheduled){
    const response = await fetch("http://my-endpoint.com/upload");
    const body = await response.json();
    return setScheduled(body)
}

export default function ViewAll(props){
    const [scheduled,setScheduled] = useState([]);
    const [loaded,setLoaded] = useState(false)

    useEffect(()=>{
        getScheduled(setScheduled).then(r=>setLoaded(true))
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            //content here
        </div>
    )
}
```

EDIT: As found in my discussion with @Virtuoz, the useEffect hook is only being called once.  When I put a print at the beginning, it only appears once, and when I put a print in the .then callback, it only is called once the barrage of requests stop.

Comment: This behaviour might be the result of constant component re-render.

Comment: useEffect should only be called on initial page load, no?

Comment: That's true, that's why it seems that ViewAll component is getting re-mounted. Sorry, I meant remount instead of re-render :)

Comment: You want to know something really weird?  The useEffect is only getting called once.  I put in a console.log and it only goes off one time.  Will add that to my post.